# Email Notification when google docs were updated

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a web-based tool that will serve as repository of all google docs of the operations. Is there a way that an email notification can be triggered when a file is updated?

I didn't try anything yet as I have no idea how it will works in google script. The only idea that I have is to put a trigger code in each file but this will not be applicable for the users.

N/A

The expected result should be any google docs that will be updated will trigger a notification email to all users.

Comment: It's possible to implement with google cloud functions. you can find more here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers

Comment: Thanks for the response Grynets. However, I didn't understand how it works. Or is it applicable to use it in my Web-based tool created in google script? Sorry I am just new here in google script and still learning. :D